# Bluetooth not working - no controller available

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu a year ago after I bought my laptop, and I have one issue with Bluetooth.

It's not working every time, it shows "BLUETOOTH NOT FOUND PLUG IN A DONGLE TO USE A BLUETOOTH". I have checked my Bluetooth is active and running but I can't use it.

[image]

It shows like this every time:

[image]

And I checked in bluetooth control to `scan on` it shows `no default controller available`. I have been struggling with this since I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: If you tried everything, we can't help you.  But you didn't thy to find out what is the BT device ;-)

Comment: You didn't provide any information to work with.

Comment: Can you please try these commands: $ sudo systemctl start hciuart $ sudo bluetoothctl

Comment: to linux genie it is the result " Failed to start hciuart.service: Unit hciuart.service not found."

Comment: what kind of information do you need

Comment: We could use results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: To Jeremy31 i have runned these commands in terminal and posting results in this link

Comment: 1-https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-from-2023-01-09-19-20-55.png

Comment: 2-https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-from-2023-01-09-19-21-15.png

Comment: 3-https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-from-2023-01-09-19-22-42.png
4-https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-from-2023-01-09-19-23-34.png

Comment: You don't have Bluetooth hardware so Bluetooth doesn't work

Comment: No i have Bluetooth hardware  my laptop had Bluetooth and i have used it before installing Ubuntu in windows

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215167

Answer (score 0):

The interim workaround is to perform the following which will flush the command history for the device that's failing to respond:

```
modprobe -r btusb && modprobe btusb
```

These commands must be run as root.

[image]

Then, bluetooth works. I am not sure for exactly how long, as it still seems to go out again after awhile.

The Ubuntu bug to track this (please ignore my link in the comments above as that is LKML territory) is, I believe, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1960016.